# Should there be an Iterator within another iterator for hierarchical data?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, iterator

I want to maintain an iterator for my list data but list data has another list within and I want to maintain iterator to that as well. Should I maintain an iterator within iterator? Should the two iterators be seperate?

```
// iterator interface
class Iterator
{
public:
   boolean hasNext() = 0;
   Object getCurrnetItem() = 0;
   Object next() = 0;
   boolean remove() = 0;
}

// this iterator will iterator the following list
std::vector<MY_SCRUCT> mList;
```

now MY_STRUCT has another std::vector in it to which I also need iterator. The following represent it as sample code:

```
struct MY_SCRUCT
{
   int numOfObjects;
   std::vector<int> data; // i need iterator for this one too!
}
```

I need to maintain iterator to both these lists so my application can at any time know what are the current selected items.

My question again is that should these iterators be separate on should one stay inside the other to correspond to that data structure?

Comment: Your class looks like an immigrant from the Java land. Please don't. You will confuse the heck out of your fellow C++ programmers. C++ has its own notion of iterators and they look nothing like those in Java. And no, you shouldn't put an iterator inside an iterator, that would be very strange indeed. Iterators are positions in a list. They don't care what's in the list and whether it does some internal structure. They only care where in the list a given element is.

Comment: +1 for you are right I took the code snippet from a book that follows java for its examples. About iterators being separate, you statement makes sense but I would still be interested in other answers because true both iterators are just positions but they are related in that one list resides inside the other.

Comment: That is a design pattern from the Gang of Four. While it is the default way to iterate in Java, it is not limited by Java, and I have seen it not only in other languages, but also in C++. That being said, Stepanov's iterators (those in the C++ standard library) are vastly superior to those in the Iterator pattern...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yes I follow GoF too and this is design pattern that obviously applies to multiple langues if not all of them. I will have to disagree with n.m on that its only good for java.

Comment: Java iterators are incompatible with the new C++11 `for` loops. `for (auto element : container)` won't work here because it explicitly uses begin and end. It's also incompatible with all existing algorithms which follow STL style. And that's more than just the Standard ones, I for instance have a `"numeric2.h"` header. Works with `boost` containers because we both agree on STL-style iterators.

Answer (score 0):

I would say keep another one inside rather than separate. Seems like good coding practice to keep relevant code togather. Also, rather than create a new one, you can create and instance of the iterator object from within itself. That way when you're doing OOP, you iterator class would have a similar structure to you struct class (keeps your code more managable and legible).

Answer (score -1):

Do all users that want to iterate over the outer type also want to iterate over the inner sequence? If the answer is not, then the clear answer is keep them separate.

Even if all use cases want to iterate over both dimensions, the question still stands in a different form. Do you want to impose that all iterations must go over both dimensions completely, does this make sense?

I personally would avoid it. You iterate over one dimensions and get `Object`, for each object *if the user wants* she can also iterate over the inner `int`s. Binding the orthogonal concepts into a single iteration is not going to help you in any way and is probably going to preclude some use cases. At the same time it will make it harder to maintain. If they are separate and you add one extra subelement, you need to provide iteration over that new subelement, but you need not touch all of the existing code that does not depend on the new feature.

Comment: The inner `(int)` is the real deal, the outer (or main) list is primarily for organizational purposes. The best analogy I can give you from functional perspective is a grocery store receives 2 trucks full of stuff one day so main list has two items (for each truck) and than the sublist contains all the stuff that came in that truck. The next day 5 new trucks came so we organized that data accordingly with 5 items in main and so on. Assume each day is separate. When I am displaying the data I want to show which item and which truck did it came in - hence the two iterators.

Comment: @zadane: you are describing a form of iteration over the elements, is that the only one? If it is, then you might want to encapsulate the objects into a `Transport` class that internally handles whether it is a car or a truck, multiple trucks or a train and provides a single iteration over the contents. A simple example of this is `std::deque`

Comment: Hmm..I thought that's how I have organized it minus the confusion with iterator part. In my real application it is batch process. Each batch can contain multiple containers and each container can contain multiple items. My data structure which are classes corresponds to this hierarchy.